# SymPy replacement with subs for Pauli symbol with label specified

Tags: sympy

```
from sympy import Wild
from sympy.physics.paulialgebra import Pauli

a = Pauli(3, label='sigma_a')
b = Pauli(3, label='sigma_b')
a
```

results in output:

<sub>3</sub>

Replacing this with 1 by specifying the label exactly works as expected:

```
# Results in "1" being printed in the notebook
a.subs(Pauli(3, label='sigma_a'), 1)
```

But a more general replacement of Pauli(3) doesn't affect the expression:

```
# No change to the expression
a.subs(Pauli(3), 1)
```

How can I use Wild or some other mechanism to say "substitute all Pauli(3) symbols, regardless of the label"? Matching and replacing is fine too, it doesn't need to be a single step using subs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pauli` has two attributes, `label` and `i`; `replace` can look for args matching a certain description and make a replacement if those conditions are met:

```
>>> a
sigma_a3
>>> a.replace(lambda a: a.func==Pauli and a.i==3, lambda a: 1) 
1
```

That says, "replace any arg whose func is Pault and has an index of 3 with 1". `replace` has a rich syntax as described in its docstring.